# Semantic segmentation with greyscale images

Tags: dataset, cnn, vgg16, pretraining

I'm trying to reproduce a research with greyscale images instead of colour images.

I have found that there are pre-trained networks, like VGG16, with ImageNet. But that dataset has colour images, and I can't use it because I'm going to use greyscale images.

Is there any pre-trained network with greyscale images?

Failing that, I can also train a network with a greyscale image dataset but **I can't find any**.

Comment: Your problem has been asked and resolved in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995977/how-can-i-use-a-pre-trained-neural-network-with-grayscale-images

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageNet, convert every image to grayscale and train VGG16.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your dataset has one value per pixel, whereas ImageNet expects 3? Just convert your data to "color images" by passing the same value on all 3 (RGB) channels.